# 2003 to 2012r2 DC migration; unable to promote target server

Tags: domain, windows-server-2012-r2, migration

I have a network with a single domain. The PDC is running Server 2003 SP1 and is unable to be upgraded. The PDC also runs DNS and DHCP for the network. I have another server running 2003 SP2, which is my BDC. I have a new server, running 2012r2 Standard, which I want to migrate AD, DNS and DHCP functions to and then decommission the two 2003 boxes.

Thus far I have raised the domain and forest functional levels from 2000 to 2003. I have joined the 2012r2 server to the domain and added the AD, DNS and DHCP rolls.

The problem comes when I try to promote the 2012r2 server to a domain controller. in the wizard I select Add a domain controller to an existing domain, specify the domain name, which is already listed and then supply credentials. When I click next, I get an error that it could not log onto the domain with the specified credential although I'm using the correct admin username and password for the domain. The only thing I notice is that the domain is specified as domainName.priv but when I enter the credentials it shows the user name as DOMAINNAME\Administrator.

I can't figure out why it wont accept the credentials as they are the same that I used when adding the 2012r2 server to the domain and was prompted.

Comment: Are you able to run AD Users and Computers from the 2012 R2 server and manage the domain?

Answer (score 0):

Did you prepare the AD scheme on your old DCs?
You first need to update them with adprep from your 2012 installation CD

adprep /forestprep /forest /userdomain /user /password

Answer (score 0):

I have also migrated my DC from 2003 to 2012 and I did not face any issue, the domain and forest funtional level was windows server 2003 and you can add all the versions of windows abover windows server 2003.

You can do couple of steps to check whether it is a DC issue or not:

1) If you have any other account with the domain admin privilages, please try to promote using those credentials.
2) Hit nslookup and check whether your DC DNS is properly resolving.
3) Check whether the account with which you are login in is locked out.